# Whitespace control in Shopify Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

Shopify recently added **whitespace control** to the Liquid templating language:
https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/basics/whitespace

You essentially add an hyphen in your tag syntax `{{- -}}`, `{%- -%}` to strip whitespace (html empty line) outputted by a tag. For example:

```
{%- assign variable = "hello" -%}
{{ variable }}
```

Renders:

```
hello
```

Instead of:

```
 
hello
```

Is there a way to turns this on for all `assign` tags? and/or all specific control flow or iteration tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed. You turn it on when you type your Liquid. Let your fingers do that talking!

If you load up your theme in a text editor, you can use the common Find All command to find all instances of assign. Use that to replace the surrounding {% %} with {%- -%}. Pretty much all there is to it. Repeat for any keywords you like.