# Shopify liquid: differences between {% %} and {%- -%}

Tags: shopify, liquid

Can anyone help me distinguish `{%  %}` and `{%- -%}`. What're the differences between those syntax. In all of my usages, I can use any of theme

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573742/whitespace-control-in-shopify-liquid?rq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only difference is that one strips the white space and the other doesn't.

So this `{%  %}` will keep any white space around it.

And this `{%- -%}` will strip the white space.

The same applies for `{{  }}` and `{{- -}}`.

Or to keep it even more simple `{{- -}}` is the same as `{{ }}` but with the strip filter applied to it so it becomes `{{ | strip }}`.

You can consider it as a shorthand method for stripping the content.

Comment: Close, but not quite: The dashes will strip whitespace surrounding the tag, while the `strip` filter will strip whitespace within the tag's results.  See https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/basics/whitespace - So for example, if you have a for-loop with a bunch of Liquid logic inside it, you'll end up printing a lot of empty lines in the resulting HTML.  However, if all your liquid tags include the hyphens, the resulting HTML will not include all the blank lines between your tags.

Comment: Thank you. So, should we always use `{%-  -%}` and `{{-  -}}` ?

Comment: @quyetdc - "Always" is a bit of a strong word - sometimes stripping out the whitespace could cause some unintended effects, especially on inline dumps. Example: `class="some-class {{ settings.some_value }}" ` is good, but `{{ class="some-class {{- settings.some_value -}}"` probably isn't.  I would certainly be willing to say that it's _usually_ a good idea to use the whitespace-stripping notation to clean up the resulting HTML though :)